# python tictactoe board add numbers to side

Tags: python

ok so here is what i'm working on for fun and practice!

i am making a game board for tic tac toe or checkers and i want it to be numbered on the side but i just cant figure out some good code for it. i have use as less code as i can hopefully someone can help me with this little challenge to figure this out.

Python 2.7.8 is being used

```
Num = 1
def P1():
    print("  ---" * game)
def P2():
    if game >= 2:
    Num+ 1
    print(str(Num) + "|    " * (game + 1))
game = int(raw_input("Game board size: "))
for i in range(game):
    P1()
    P2()
    P1()
```

what i am hoping to get out of this is as shown below.

```
   1    2    3
  ---  ---  ---
1|    |    |    |    
  ---  ---  ---
  ---  ---  ---
2|    |    |    |    
  ---  ---  ---
  ---  ---  ---
3|    |    |    |    
  ---  ---  ---
```

My result from my code is as followed:

```
Game board size: 3
  ---  ---  ---
1|    |    |    |    
  ---  ---  ---
  ---  ---  ---
1|    |    |    |    
  ---  ---  ---
  ---  ---  ---
1|    |    |    |    
  ---  ---  ---
```

Comment: Show expected output vs actual.

Comment: What do you expect `Num+ 1` to do?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 with `from __future__ import print_function` or Python 3? Python 3 has `input` instead of `raw_input`. Please set the appropriate tag and clarify in your question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i have edited my question Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Also show what you are actually getting. I am pretty sure you have bigger issues to fix than getting the numbers working.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i once again edited my code to be more specific. may i ask what you think my "bigger issues to fix " is exactly?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that your output did not match the expected until you updated your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with your code you just needed to pass the row number you were currently printing to the `P2()` method and needed to print a row of numbers across the top. This should work.

```
def P0(num):
    for i in range(num-1):
        print "    " + str(i+1),
    print("    " + str(num))
def P1():
    print("  ---" * game)
def P2(i):
    print(str(i+1) + "|    " * (game + 1))
game = int(input("Game board size: "))
P0(game)
for i in range(game):
    P1()
    P2(i)
    P1()
```

Comment: thanks for the help but your code you added doesn't quit work yet i'm getting en error. the line print("    " + str(i+1), end='')   you get syntax error so i try a couple of things and and i am guessing instead of " = " after end you wanted + but i get end is not defined do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry I was using Python3 syntax. I edited my answer. Let me know if this works now

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't include the top number strip

```
def P1():
    print(" " + (" ---" * game))

def P2():
    print(str(i+1) + ("|   " * (game + 1)))

game = 3

P1()
for i in range(game):
    P2()
    P1()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll just leave this here, as found in some old scripts of mine.

*Note, that this is far from being perfect; it will e.g. break if the size exceeds 9 as it gets 2 characters wide as a string then...*

```
from __future__ import print_function

def draw_board(size, state):
    print(' |' + '|'.join(' {} '.format(x) for x in range(1, size + 1)) + '|')
    for y in range(1, size + 1):
        print('-+' + '---+' * size)
        print('{}|'.format(y), end='')
        for x in range(1, size + 1):
            marker = ' '
            if state[x - 1][y - 1] is not None:
                marker = state[x - 1][y - 1]
            print(' {} |'.format(marker), end='')
        print()
    print('-+' + '---+' * size)
    print()


def put(x, y, marker, state):
    if state[x][y] is None:
        state[x][y] = marker
    else:
        raise Exception('Place already occupied.')


def check_winner(state):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 3
    state = [[None] * size for _ in range(size)]
    draw_board(size, state)
    put(1, 1, 'x', state)
    draw_board(size, state)
    put(0, 1, 'o', state)
    draw_board(size, state)
```

This script, if run as-is, yields the following output:

```
 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
-+---+---+---+
1|   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+
2|   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+
3|   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+

 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
-+---+---+---+
1|   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+
2|   | x |   |
-+---+---+---+
3|   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+

 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
-+---+---+---+
1|   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+
2| o | x |   |
-+---+---+---+
3|   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+
```

The rest shall be left to you, OP ;)